# Two level ssh with capistrano

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, capistrano

I'm using capistrano for a long time to deploy my code through ssh, but this time our server architecture is quite different.

We got our server at user@master-ip, containing multiple VMs including the one I want to deploy to. But it is only locally accessible through ssh user@local-vm-ip.

So ... how can I configure capistrano to use two level ssh ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

SSH supports a `ProxyCommand` option that allows for this. Capistrano also recognizes this config and will load an SSH config file automatically if it is placed in `.ssh/config` within your project (i.e where you run `cap`).

Create a `.ssh/config` file within your Capistrano project with these contents:

```
Host my-server
  ProxyCommand ssh user@master-ip exec nc local-vm-ip %p
```

This tells SSH that when you `ssh my-server`, what you really want it to do is first connect to `user@master-ip`, and then from there make the connection to `local-vm-ip`. In other words `my-server` is an alias for this two-level SSH setup (you can give it whatever name you like).

Then in your Capistrano config, use `"my-server"` (or whatever you chose) as the address of the server you want to deploy to. Capistrano will automatically use `.ssh/config` and take care of the two-level SSH.